# tmp/deployimages/${MACHINE}/*.wix.xz deleted when I build a different Image

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, yocto, openembedded

In my Yocto build I have to build different images for the same machine. The problem I am facing is that when I build one images, all the artifacts of the previous image are deleted from the deploy directory.

I have included `INHERIT += "rm_work"` in the `local.conf` but I don't think this is causing issues, as I have also added `RM_WORK_EXCLUDE += " ${IMAGE_NAMES}"`

Comment: I suggest to [edit] your question and copy&paste your configuration files as a [mre]. But I think this question might be off-topic here because it is not about programming but about using a tool. Maybe you can post it on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.